# Delete a row of data with a destroy button in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, sql-delete

I have an index of all items from database listed in my view.  I want to create a destroy button to destroy the current record in the database using Ruby on Rails 4.  Here is my code:

```
<div>
   <h1>All Incomes</h1>

  <% @user_incomes.each do |income| %>
  <div>
    <p><%= income.title %></p>
    <p><%= income.description %></p>
    <p><%= number_to_currency(income.amount) %>
    <p><%= income.user_id %></p>
    <%= button_to "Destroy", {action: "destroy", id: income.id}, method: :destroy, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
  </div>
    <br />
  <%end%>
</div>
```

My Income Controller:

```
class IncomesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize, only: [:new, :index, :show, :create]
  def index
    @incomes = Income.all #income refers to the db model income
    @user_incomes = Income.all.where(:user_id=>current_user.id)
  end

  def show
    @income = Income.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @income = Income.new
  end

  def create
    @income = Income.create(income_params)
  end

  def destroy
    @income.destroy
  end

  ## Strong Parameters alias Rails 3's attr_accessible
  private
    def income_params
      params.require(:income).permit(:title, :user_id, :description, :type, :amount)
    end

    def declare_income
      @income = Income.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

Here is my route file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'member_content/new'

  #get 'sessions/new'  ## this is generated with rails g controller sessions new
  resources :sessions
  resources :incomes
  resources :users
  resources :abl_deductions
  get 'main/index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
  get 'content', to: 'member_content#new',  as: 'content'
  get 'add_income', to: 'incomes#new', as: 'add_income'
  get 'add_deduction', to: 'abl_deductions#new', as: 'add_deduction'
  get 'deductions', to: 'abl_deductions#index', as: 'deductions'

end
```

I am newb to rails, would it be easier for this action if I had use a scaffold with `rails generate scaffold`?

Comment: You need to have a `destroy` method in your controller that intercepts this call, plus link that button through to the right URL.

Comment: How to link the button through the right URL?   Can I just call the method instead of going to the url?  Also I want this index page to just refresh after deleting the record.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your controller is called `IncomesController`. When you run `bin/rails routes` in your app folder, you should also see something like:

```
DELETE /incomes/:id(.:format)      incomes#destroy
```

To achieve this, you need to have proper `routes.rb` records. Easy thing to achieve standard CRUD operations over incomes is to have `resources :incomes` in `routes.rb`

You also need to have `destroy` method in `IncomesController` to perform actual destroy.

Comment: Does "def destroy
    @income.destroy
  end" actually destroy the individual record?

Comment: also try in your view providing `income_path(income)` in your view

Comment: @WiselyWong yes it does, if you write it that way, but first you need to have `@income` assigned, so first line of `destroy` method should be something like `@income = Income.find(params[:id])`

Comment: in the view?  what is the "income" argument do in this case?  income_path is my index view(the html.erb) in my question.

Comment: @WiselyWong `income` comes from you iteration over `@user_incomes` (line 3 in your view), I meant something like `<%= button_to "Destroy", class:"btn btn-primary", income_path(income),method: :delete%>`